# Please clarify the meaning of $\text{End}_R(R_R, R_R) \cong R$

Tags: ring-theory, notation, modules

First of all, I have no idea what $\text{End}_R(R_R, R_R) \cong R$ is even supposed to mean. The $R$ in $\text{End}_R$ is supposed to be a category, but the $R$ in $R_R$ is an object in that category. So I don't even know what the question is asking.

Comment: Your title indicates that you are asking for a proof, but your question indicates that you are asking for a clarification of notation. Which is it?

Comment: I am asking for a clarification of notation.

Comment: You should give a citation or other clarification to where you see this notation being used.  Almost always an author will introduce and define notation before using it, by very nature of a useful notation being a compact way to avoid repeating some basic ideas over and over (the ability of skillful notation to hide details while suggesting intuitive properties).

Comment: It seems likely the user (or whoever is authoring the user's material) is confusing $Hom(R_R,R_R)=End(R_R)$.  Personally I like the convention of specifying the rings of interest in the End notation as subscripts. So for example if $_RM_S$ and $_RN_S$ were $R,S$ bimodules, and I wanted to write the set of $S$ linear maps between them, I would say $Hom(M_S, N_S)$. As far as I can tell this eliminates the need for another subscript outside the parens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with hardmath's comment that notation should be referenced in context, but here's my best guess.

$R$ is a ring. $R_R$ is a notation for the ring $R$, considered as a module over itself (i.e., as an object in the category $R-\textbf{mod}$). $\mathrm{End}_R$ refers the endomorphism ring of endomorphisms in the category $R-\textbf{mod}$; i.e., the $R$ subscript in $\mathrm{End}_R$ is short for $R-\textbf{mod}$. As the endomorphism ring and $R$ are both rings, the isomorphism in question in as isomorphism of rings.

Comment: It might help to clarify the claimed isomorphism to specify that $R$ is a ring *with unity*, which simplifies the characterization of endomorphisms $R\to R$ (as $R$-modules).